# How do I uninstall an administrator app?

Tags: samsung-mobile, galaxy, s5

Basically, I was trying to install a pandora one apk mod and I downloaded an app called "phonebooster". Since then, 10 seconds after I open the google play store, an app pops up! Also, when I'm watching a youtube video, or just on youtube, an ad video pops up! Last thing is that when I'm on a website, sometimes it will redirect me to a popup add bit it's the same one everytime! I think that this all has to do the "phone booster apk" app. Its an administrative app but when I go to Settings -> Security -> Device Administrators and try to uncheck something, it brings my back to the security page and does nothing. I really really need some help!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to follow this path i.e.;
move to Settings->Security->Device Administrator &
de-select the app you want to unistall.
Then, open the Applications and force stop that app and then uninstall it. It works for me, hope it will works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to SETTINGS->Location and Security-> Device Administrator and deselect the admin which you want to uninstall.

Now uninstall the application. If it still says you need to deactivate the application before uninstalling, you may need to Force Stop the application before uninstalling.

Also visit [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387582/how-to-remove-an-app-with-active-device-admin-enabled-on-android)