# Can I develop the app which should never delete.(Android)

Tags: android

Can I develop the app which should never delete even after reset the mobile Or It should block to RESET the mobile.
If any suggestion please help out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any installed app can be deleted so needs to be part of firmware/custom ROM which can survive reset.

Comment: It's like a bad software, a friend. Villainous software.

Comment: I am working for a company which requires me to restrict the app to be uninstalled even after reseting the phone to factory settings by employee.

Comment: There is no way to do this without installing it in the system partition, which requires either root privileges or embedding the app in the firmware/ROM.

Comment: Then how to embed our app to the firmware?

Comment: Can you please provide me some link to add my app to firmware ?

Comment: You can't simply add an app to the firmware of an existing device. You would have to make a custom build of the Android OS that includes your app, then force people to flash it over their current Android OS. Most people can't do this anyway because the firmware is locked by the manufacturer (and few people would know how or be willing to risk doing something so invasive). Furthermore, I would seriously reconsider my employment with a company that wants to install their app in the firmware of my phone so as to make it factory-reset-proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to require employees to install an app that provides whatever certificates/credentials necessary to access company resources. This app would use the [Device Administration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) APIs to restrict certain policies on the device. As long as the app is enabled as a Device Administrator in the settings of the device, the user can't manually uninstall it. (They can still factory-reset their phone, but in that case they will no longer have the app and so lose whatever certificates/credentials allowing access to company resources.)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387582/how-to-remove-an-app-with-active-device-admin-enabled-on-android