# Package com.harish signatures do not match the previously installed version

Tags: android, google-play-services

Application package name `com.harish` signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!

My app was there in `playstore` with version 1.0, now I need to update the app with version 1.1.
When I did migration like this, its failing and giving below error.

**Step1:**
 Freshly install the app from `playstore`.

**Step 2:**
 Generated the `Apk` with release mode and kept in device.

**Step 3:**
 When tap on `apk` its ask `install` after that its show app not installed and gave below `error`

**Package `com.harish` signatures do not match the previously installed `version`; ignoring!**

I'm signing the `apk` with same `signature`.
I have verified the `apk` certificates, both are same.

Verifying the certs like this [How do I find out which keystore was used to sign an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331469/how-do-i-find-out-which-keystore-was-used-to-sign-an-app)

Straging thing was when I'm upload the `apk` into play store, its uploaded `successfully`!!! and I'm able to `update` the app from `playstore`.

Then why i'm getting this error

Comment: Look into this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709102/package-signatures-do-not-match-the-previously-installed-version/41711890

Comment: Question is did you use Google Play App Signing?

Comment: Means is there any setting in google playstore like this Google Play App Signing?

Comment: Thank you **Selvin** , someone enable google play app signing, because of that its failing local migration

Answer (score 1):

I think If the version of the app that you have installed was not built with the same keystore/signing certificate it will have a different signature. By default, each machine will have a different debug certificate unless you specify how it should be signed.
check [google documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) for it

In order to proceed with the installation, you must uninstall the existing version and then try again

Comment: Same apk only i have uploaded the google playstore successfully, from there app is getting updated. if is there any keystore/signing  issue it won't allow us right.

Comment: Uninstall previously installed app from device and then you check any app related data remaining on your device. If existing remove app data completely and try to install the new app.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **Selvin** , someone enable google play app signing in my google playstore account , because of that its failing local migration

Comment: Hi! I have exactly the same trouble as you! Could you tell me how did you solve it?

Comment: i am also facing the same kind of issue, not able to install the release build created from android studio on top of playstore build unless uninstalled.