# Android Package signatures do not match

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.2

I just imported a project in Android Studio 3.2.1
And synced successfully. The project imported was using

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.4"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

And now I changed version according to 28

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

So I have already application installed in my smartphone.
When I try to install its giving message "package signatures do not match the previously installed version". And most important I cannot uninstall the application, I need to only update it. What should I do to make it work correctly?

Comment: You have to uninstall the previously installed version first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127260/package-com-harish-signatures-do-not-match-the-previously-installed-version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489567/manually-installing-an-updated-apk-fails-with-signatures-do-not-match-the-previ?rq=1

Comment: `And most important I cannot uninstall the application, I need to only update it` You have to Uninstall it ,,  otherwise new App will not be installed.

Comment: From where you have installed previous app from `play store` or different computer ?

Comment: previous version was unsigned apk from ubuntu system

Comment: @Ankita obviously, but how do you uninstall it via the command line?

Answer (score 0):

> When you sign an APK, the signing tool attaches the public-key certificate to the APK—the same is true when signing an app bundle. The public-key certificate serves as a "fingerprint" that uniquely associates the APK or app bundle to you and your corresponding private key. This helps Android ensure that any future updates to your app are authentic and come from the original author. The key used to create this certificate is called the app signing key.
>
> A keystore is a binary file that contains one or more private keys.
>
> Every app must use the same certificate throughout its lifespan in order for users to be able to install new versions as updates to the app.

For more details: 
[Sign your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

Answer (score -1):

sudo mv /data/system/packages.xml /data/system/packages.bkp
reboot