# Beta by Crashlytics: Upgrade apk different signatures

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm trying to use Crashlytics beta but everytime i'm trying to instal (via Beta app) i'm getting "App not installed"

In my device I have 1.0.0 installed from Play store
After few changed in code I wanted to release 1.0.1 so I generated new apk using the SAME RELEASE KEY that the apk (1.0.0) in store generated from.

And I'm getting "App not installed" over and over again.

I downloaded the apk (1.0.0), installed via ADB 
and than i tried to install the latest apk (1.0.1) and getting:

INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.xyx.abcd signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!

How can it be???
Thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package signatures do not match the previously installed version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709102/package-signatures-do-not-match-the-previously-installed-version)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot install your builded apk by AS over Google Play apk because they always have different signatures. When you updload the apk to Google Play, Google re-signs the APKs with the original app signing key you provided and delivers your app to the user. You can read it here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

So to test the update you need apk v1.0.0 with your release key (just generate it with AS) and new v1.0.1 also generated and signed by AS. This two apks will have the same signature, but when you upload the v1.0.1 apk to market it also will be re-signed.

Comment: Hi dantes_21, So in other words, I cant simulate upgrade with play store installed version??

Comment: When I tested a DB migration in my application I didn't find any solution. So I just tested on apks that signed with my release key. This is also will be simulating of update, but with your release key and not a deployment key by Google Play

Comment: I mean you can install v1.0.0 apk that you uploaded before to Google Play (if you saved it somewhere) and install over it new v1.0.1 apk. It will behaves like an update that will be produced in Google Play when you later upload a new apk to market

Comment: Or you maybe can use Alpha and Beta tests in Google Play. I did not test it, but it might work

Comment: dantes_21 Thanks for the detailed answer. Seems like my issue related to App signing in google play. I'll investigate it and share more details

Comment: So issue still exist. Tried everything. help is needed. (I know for sure that upgrade can be made from when installed from play and upgrading from Beta.
Google play app signing is enabled, and probably causes it. any Crashlytics Beta people here?