# Flutter run from terminal works while manually not

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

When I run `flutter build apk --release` everything works just fine, In addition when I connect my phone to the computer and run `flutter install -v` everything is ok. Also when I run `flutter run -v` my app is working on my phone just fine.

BUT when I'm sending the apk manually to my phone, install and open my app, it's stuck on the splash screen.

I don't know what can case it not to work manually (since I cannot track my logs).

- I'm using firebase, my `google-services.json` is up to date.
- flutter doctor is just fine.
- android SDK version 30.0.2.
- app/build.gradle compileSdkVersion 30.
- gradle version 6.6.1.
- classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
- classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'

Any suggestions how to validate my application? What can case such a problem?

Thanks you!!!

## More Information

The only error on `flutter run` is:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.name.name signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
```

but as I said before the `flutter run` do works and my app uploads correctly, so I think it is not related to my problem.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your current app off your phone or emulator and then installing it?

Comment: Yes I did that so many time, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests using `flutter run -v` I encountered that in some cases I'm getting:

```
Unhandled exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)
```

I do work with shared_preferences package and that answer sure solve my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/63027655/12695188

Although this is a specific solution I will describe what I have done in order to find my problem:

1. flutter pub get
2. flutter build apk --debug
3. flutter build apk --profile
4. flutter build apk --release
5. connect your physical device to your computer
6. flutter install -v (to your physical device)
7. flutter run -v

Solve each problem you find on `flutter run -v`.

Hope this will help someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

Have You implemented release SHA keys ?

Comment: Yes I have checked that my flutter project SHA keys are same as my gradle signature release SHA

Comment: Keep in mind that there are two types of SHA keys. For debugging and for release, I also encountered this bug once and in my case it was because my SHA keys were not entered in Firebase. Make sure to put both of them especially if You are using google authentication on Firebase

Comment: If the above does not help make sure to check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709102/package-signatures-do-not-match-the-previously-installed-version

Comment: First of all thanks for the help @Nedim Karavdic. I have just checked and my release and debug SHA keys are placed on firebase correctly.

Comment: Several devs had same problem with their projects, one of the things that worked for vast majority of them was the command : adb uninstall "com.domain.yourapp"

Comment: I run that command and it does solved my "signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!" error on `flutter run` but still my problem is to run the app manually (also my new users, who had never installed the app, are facing the same problem). But I think you were right that the problem may be due to authentication failure, I'm just checking this out at the very moments.

Comment: What type of authentication are You using ?

Comment: sms verification

Comment: SMS verification can be tested only on real devices, emulators are not able to do it

Comment: Yes I wrote on my question "when I connect my phone to the computer ". Sorry for not been clear with that. I'm using my physical device.

Comment: Check this url, there are several possible answers, just make sure to notify me if one of them works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709102/package-signatures-do-not-match-the-previously-installed-version

Comment: I have tried this issue but I really think it is not related to my problem. This link supports debug run while I'm trying to achieve release running.