# Mobile app crash after flutter update. What to do?

Tags: flutter, dart, crash, updates

After a recent flutter update, my app stopped working. Throws out from the mobile application. Can you help me? I have got this error:

```
adb: failed to install /Users/User/Desktop/project/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk: Failure[INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.package.name: signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
```

Before that everything worked. I don't know what to do, please help. The command adb uninstall <package_name> won't help. The project is already on Google Play

I tried reinstalling. Install the original version of the mobile application. update all dependencies, but nothing helped

Answer (score 0):

that's because it's different from the previous version you can see in a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709102/package-signatures-do-not-match-the-previously-installed-version/53396378#53396378)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my case, the application is already launched in the play market. Need another solution