# I Was Stuck On This Error. I Don't know How To Solve This Error?

Tags: android, flutter, error-handling

adb: failed to install C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NETPAIR\ngms5\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk: Failure
[INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.ngms signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
Error launching application on RMX3085.

I Was Try To Run But Always I Face This Error

Comment: It can be that you used a different jks file to sign the apk file. You can uninstall the previous application from the device and then try installing the new one

Comment: [See this answer may be it will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709102/package-signatures-do-not-match-the-previously-installed-version)

Comment: Uninstall your old app and then install this new build