# Can't delete self-programmed app

Tags: android

Recently I bought a new computer and installed Android Studio on it. I transferred all te files necessary from my old computer so I could continue my work on my app.
The code was built and ready to upload to my device, but I got the message ' INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES', and Android Studio advised me to uninstall my app from my phone and try again.
Whe I tried this, I noticed the 'delete' button was greyed out, and in Settings -> Apps -> TestApp (name of my app) I noticed the buttons for 'Force quit', 'Move to SD-card', and 'Clear Cache' were all greyed out.
Is there anything I can do to make my phone delete my app, and to enable these functions in the future?
**EDIT:** after running `adb uninstall mypackagename` I got the result `Failure [DELETE_FAILED_DEVICE_POLICY_MANAGER]`. My app uses the Device Policy Manager for locking and unlocking the phone.

**SOLVED**: After looking up the error code, I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5387620/3594414) at StackOverflow.

Thank you very much everyone!

Comment: adb uninstall <package>. it didn't help?

Comment: Have you tried deleting app after rebooting your phone?

Comment: try using 3rd party tool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running `adb uninstall mypackagename` like [Umar Hussain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4428159/umar-hussain) pointed out, I got the result Failure `[DELETE_FAILED_DEVICE_POLICY_MANAGER]`. My app uses the Device Policy Manager for locking and unlocking the phone.

After looking up the error code, I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5387620/3594414) at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command from adb, after connecting your phone to pc in usb debugging mode

```
adb uninstall yourapppackagename
```

Package name you can see from the app info in the phone or packageid from your app gradle file